# Fix (Stick) UI Grid column headers when grid's vertical scollbar is disabled

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I have disabled UI Grid vertical scroll bar and have just page scroll bar with more than 200 records displayed at a time.
But when the page is scrolled the grid headers are not visible on the screen.
Also the horizontal scroll bar is present right at the bottom of the screen making it inconvenient as the user would have to scroll right till the bottom to access it making the grid column headers invisible.

Comment: provide the link for the plunker

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/yjV6ytBNtu1R0KskqyCD?p=preview